# Interop Table pasteSpecial error "command failed"

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop, copy-paste

I have the below code to copy and paste a table in my word document

```
oWord.Selection.MoveDown(WdUnits.wdLine, 3);
oWord.Selection.Tables[1].Select();
oWord.Selection.Copy();
oWord.Selection.MoveDown(WdUnits.wdLine, 6);
oWord.Selection.PasteAndFormat(WdRecoveryType.wdTableOriginalFormatting);
```

it gets to the last line then throws a COMException error with message "command failed"

Is there a better way to copy the table 2 lines below the current one?

Comment: What does the `Selection` property contain at that fifth line?  Maybe it's not able to paste into it.

Comment: @AnnL.: it's blank, in the end I changed it to `oWord.Selection.Paste();` and now it works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't the answer to my question about using **PasteAndFormat** but in the end I changed the last line to:

```
oWord.Selection.Paste();
```

and now it works.